# Find the smallest number divisible by $204$ the digits of which sum to $204$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The problem asks us to find the smallest number divisible by $204$, with sum of its digits equal to $204$.

I totally don't know what to use here. I would be thankful for any hint that would enable me to get "unstuck" with this problem.

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: I don't know - the necessary condition for the number is that it must be divisible by $2^2, 3, 17$. Divisibility by $3$ is for free as the sum of the number would be divisible by $3$. So we're looking for some kind of even number with digits that sum to $204$, and that number must be divisible by $17$. But how to write that "mathematically", in order to work with that, I have no idea...

Comment: Just to put a limit on it, clearly $224444884488448844884488448844884488$ fulfills the conditions. ($2244$ then $8$ copies of $4488$).

Comment: Better lower bound: $9999999999999999224444884488$.

Comment: Best lower bound: $99999899999999999999988$ (with thanks to Robert Israel).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are at least $23$ digits (since $22 \times 9 = 198 < 204$).  If it has 
$23$ digits, its digit sum is $3$ less than the largest possible digit-sum for a $23$-digit number.  Your number is divisible by $4$, so the last two digits
can't be $98$ or $78$, but they could be $88$.  So try $23$-digit numbers of the form 
$10^{23} - 12 - 10^j$ where $2 \le j \le 22$.

Comment: That was spookily simultaneous... nice answer and reasonably similar to mine :-) with perhaps a little more direction from you

Comment: To simplify the calculation, all you need is for $10^j\equiv 10^{23}-12\pmod{17}$.. Since $10$ is a generatore modulo $17$, this is possible unless $10^{23}-12\equiv 0\pmod{17}$.

Answer (score 2):

What is $204$ divided by $9$? This will take you to your minimum number of digits in the answer, although you may need to increase by one more digit to find a suitable number

Then you need to think about getting the right mix of digits in place for the various prime factors of $204 = 2^2\cdot 3 \cdot 17$. Getting the digit sum to $204$ will automatically adjust for divisibility by $3$ however. Divisibility by $4$ rests on the last two digits, but divisibility by $17$ can be affected by any digit in the resulting number.

Can you work out what (say) $10^{23} \bmod 17$ is?